# How to add checkbox and get the values in webpage using magento?

Tags: php, magento

While creating an website, I want to add a checkbox on the checkout page for the same day delivery option, so if the checkbox is checked I will update the delivery charge.

How can I update the delivery prices based on the check box value at checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many shipping options you offer, but IMHO the better way of doing this is :

Adding a new delivery method "Next Day Delivery".

Change the shipping_method.phtml file (in your package/theme/checkout/onepage/) to change the display of this method as just a checkbox that will dispatch the javascript event to update pricing.

Comment: I just want 2 methods. same day delivery or next day, can you please help me i couldn't get you.

Comment: If you have several shipping method (I suggest OwebiaShipping to configure more than default method), the default shipping page show a block for each method with a radio button to pick the one you want. You have to change the template (it's checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml for this page) to replace the normal behaviour by the one you want (only show the block for method1 and replace the block for the method2 by a checkbox, then link the javascript action of the radio button to the checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Magento Extra Fee Extension](http://www.magikcommerce.com/magento-extra-fee-extension) It will allow you to add the check box on checkout page with additional amount which will be added to shipping amount if check box is selected.

Comment: its not what i want and its not free.

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution with free extention here is the link http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-flat-shipping.html